# Zend_Filter_Input how to filter and validate multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, multidimensional-array

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.3.

Filtering a single dimensional array (e.g. param[]=2&param[]=3&param[]=7) is done automatically by Zend_Filter_Input recursively (i.e. similar to a string).

But if we have a multidimensional array (e.g. param[0][]=2&param[0][]=3&param[1][]=7&param[1][]=8), I can't seem to be able to validate it. I receive a notice

`<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\library\Zend\Filter\StringTrim.php</b> on line <b>99</b><br />`

Do you know how to filter and validate a multidimensional array in Zend_Filter_Input ?